# Relation between eigenvalues of original and transformed matrices

Tags: covariance-matrix, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

Let the matrix $X$ be some data arranged in rows. Consider the following eigenvalue decomposition $X^\top X = Q \Theta Q^\top=\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_iq_iq_i^\top$ where $q_i$ are the eigenvectors and $\theta_i$ are the eigenvalues. Now I apply some transformation to the data $Y=XT$ where $T$ is a symmetric matrix. Then the matrix $Y^\top Y$ can be re-written as 
$$
\begin{aligned}
 Y^\top Y &= T (X^\top X)T \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i Tq_i q_i^\top T \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i (q_i^\top T^\top T q_i ) \frac{Tq_i}{||Tq_i ||} \left(\frac{Tq_i}{||Tq_i ||}\right)^\top \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i u_i u_i^\top
\end{aligned}
$$

I want that $\alpha_i$ must be the eigenvalues of $Y^\top Y$ and $u_i$ must be the eigenvectors of $Y^\top Y$. While $u_i$ have a unit norm, they are not orthogonal, i.e. $u_i^\top u_j \neq 0$. Is it possible to get a relationship between eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $X^\top X$ and $Y^\top Y$.

Comment: Your formulas for matrix multiplication are incorrect.  For example, $(Q\Theta Q^\prime)_{ij} = \sum_{k}^n\sum_{l=1}^n q_{ik} \theta_{kl} q_{jl}.$

Comment: @whuber. $\Theta$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

Comment: Okay--but your formula is still incorrect; it just simplifies a little because $\theta_{kl} = \theta_k \delta_{kl}.$  In particular, the expressions "$q_i$" make no sense when $Q$ is a matrix.

Comment: $q_i$ is the ith eigenvector of $X^\top X$ arranged along columns of $Q$

Comment: I see: I needed to read your post more carefully.  Now that I am, let me ask this: what are you assuming about "$D^{-1/2}$" and why don't you just express it as an arbitrary (presumably invertible) matrix?

Comment: Sure. I changed the question. Now I just have a symmetric transformation matrix.